# Django 3.0.3 IntegrityError FOREIGN KEY constraint failed when making changes to db

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

I have two models in my database, an 'Account' model (which is a custom user model) and a 'Return' model.

My database worked fine up to the point of adding the 'Return' model, which has a ForeignKey relationship with the 'User' model, which I suspect is causing the problem. (Each return belongs to an existing user. In the admin panel, the option box is populated with existing users so I thought this was working correctly?)

Appreciate any help with this!

Error:

IntegrityError at /admin/returns/return/add/

FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/returns/return/add/
Django Version:     3.0.3
Exception Type:     IntegrityError
Exception Value:

FOREIGN KEY constraint failed

Here is my Return app's models.py:

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

# Create your models here.
class Return(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="returns", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    last_edited = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    TAX_YEAR_CHOICES = [
    ('2019', '2019'),
    ('2020', '2020'),
    ('2021', '2021'),
    ]

    tax_year_ending = models.CharField(
        choices=TAX_YEAR_CHOICES,
        max_length=4,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )

    RETURN_STATUS_CHOICES = [
    ('1', 'In progress'),
    ('2', 'Completed, awaiting review'),
    ('3', 'Completed, under review'),
    ('4', 'Completed, awaiting client action'),
    ('5', 'Submitted to HMRC'),
    ]

    return_status = models.CharField(
        choices=RETURN_STATUS_CHOICES,
        max_length=1,
        default=1,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
```

Here is my custom user class (also setup in settings.py):

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length=60, unique=True) # tells Django this is the unique ID

    #following required for the AbstractBaseUser class
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    #tell django we want to use email as our username field (for logins)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    #tells Django to user AccountManager
    objects = AccountManager()

    #tell django which fields are required on registration:
    #REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    #what to return when we print the Account object
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

#following required for AbstractBaseUser class
    #does the user have permissions, yes if is_admin
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

Here is the post request information from the errog log:
user

'3'

last_edited_0

'2020-05-03'

last_edited_1

'13:01:23'

tax_year_ending

'2019'

return_status

'3'

_addanother

'Save and add another'

(I have confirmed that there is a user with pk '3')

Thanks again, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to record the instance of user on behalf of pk number:

```
User.objects.get(pk=3)
```

Comment: Hi Renaud, thanks so much for answering, really appreciate it.

Could you please explain in a little more detail? I am trying to make changes to my database from the Admin area. 

Also it doesn't make sense to have to record a specific pk number, as this will change based on whichever user that the 'return' I am editing belongs to? Hope that makes sense and thanks again!

Comment: From what I understood on django website https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/ ForeignKey field should contain instance of linked table object (for datas integrity) to make it simple it works on the same way than you can not recourt string in an integrer field. Recording instance can be a hard gymnastic at the beginning, but can offer you Nice thing as accessing to all fields of the User objects without searching in the User table. Unfortunatly I'm not using thé admin area to make changes in the dB so, I dont know how to proceed for that.